# Change only the default links color in CSS

Tags: css, colors

I am trying to make some small adjustments to a very big website (not did by me).
The main colors of the site are red and black. 
Now there are many css classes to define the appareance of the links, however some links are still with the default blue color (without classes applied).
I have tried adding this to the main css file:

```
a:link {
    color: #900;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
a:hover {
    color: #000;
}
```

but this change the appareance of the links with the right colors too. For instance: below, in the same css file there are these classes:

```
.linkCat {
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.linkCat:hover {
    color: #900;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

My changes will override the behaviour of these classes too.

I would like to know if there is some way to change the style only to the links without style already applied.

I repeat: the website is really big, i don't like to modify every single page to add a class to the links.

Thank you.

Comment: ugh that is ugly, why not apply a style to all `a` items, then generalize the class?  for instance, `.myLink {//put in the style you want }`.  then find each occurrence of hyperlinks and if it does not have a class add myLink as its class.  In this way you wont "break" what's already there...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put the following at the top of the css file

```
a {
    color: #900;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
a:hover {
    color: #000;
}
```

If that does not help, use a web inspector to see what overrides the problematic styles.